# C++ Linked List implementation using smart pointers - 'head' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, linked-list, smart-pointers

I'm having a problem understanding why my `head` node is not declared as being usable within the scope of my `Deque.cpp` functions.

I've currently only written the `print_queue()` function.

I thought it was because my head wasn't initialized to be anything - but then when I tried to create a `Deque::Deque()` constructor to initialize, I got a compiling error saying that it was explicitly-defaulted and that I couldn't make a constructor for it.

What's the best way to approach this issue?

#### Deque.cpp

```
#include "Deque.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void Deque::insert_front(int)
{
}

void Deque::insert_back(int)
{
}

int Deque::remove_front()
{
    return 0;
}

int Deque::remove_back()
{
    return 0;
}

int Deque::peek_front() const
{
    return 0;
}

int Deque::peek_back() const
{
    return 0;
}

bool Deque::empty() const
{
    return 0;
}

int Deque::size() const
{
    return 0;
}

void print_queue(std::string& label)
{
    Node* p = head;
    cout << "This is the linked list: " << endl;

    while ( p != NULL)
        {
            cout << head << endl;
        }

}
```

#### Deque.h

```
#include "Node.cpp"
#include <memory>


class Deque{
public:
    Deque() = default;
    Deque(const Deque&);
    ~Deque(); //must use constant space
    Deque& operator=(const Deque&); //we can use assignment in this assignement lols.


    void insert_front(int); //Must run in O(1) time
    void insert_back(int);

    int remove_front(); // O(1) - if the deque is empty - throw a runtime_error
    // (this error class is defined in the stdexcept library file)
    int remove_back();

    int peek_front() const;  //throw run_time if empty, return value dont remove
    int peek_back() const;

    bool empty() const;

    int size() const; //O(1) - return number of stored items in deque
    int size_LL = 0;

    void print_queue(const std::string& label) const; //prints all nodes in queue,
    //together with pointers to head and tail and also size of queue.
    //routine calls the node output function - not tested

    //helper methods - deep copy, used by copy and operator=
    Deque deep_copy(const Deque&);

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> tail;

    friend Node;
};
```

#### Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Node& n) {
    return out << &n << ": " << n.val << " -> " << n.next.get();
}
```

#### Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Node {
public:
    Node(const Node& n) : val{n.val}, next{}
    {
    }
    Node(int v, std::unique_ptr<Node> n) : val{v}, next{move(n)}
    {
    }
    Node(int v) : val{v}
    {
    }

private:
    int val = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next = nullptr;

    friend class Deque;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Node&);
};

#endif
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Deque.cpp"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    Deque dq1;

    cout << dq1.empty() << " - 1" << endl;

    dq1.insert_front(42);
    dq1.insert_back(216);

    cout << dq1.peek_front() << " - 42" << endl;
    cout << dq1.peek_back() << " - 216" << endl;
    cout << dq1.size() << " - 2" << endl;

    dq1.print_queue("dq1 before copy constructor and copy assignment");

    Deque dq2(dq1);
    dq2.print_queue("dq2 after copy constructor");
    Deque dq3;
    dq3 = dq1;

    dq3.print_queue("dq3 after copy assignment");

    cout << dq1.remove_front() << " - 42" << endl;
    cout << dq1.remove_back() << " - 216" << endl;
    dq1.print_queue("dq1 should be empty");

    cout << dq2.peek_front() << " - 42" << endl;
    cout << dq2.peek_back() << " - 216" << endl;

    dq3.print_queue("After two removes from dq1");

    cout << dq3.peek_front() << " - 42" << endl;
    cout << dq3.peek_back() << " - 216" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `void print_queue(std::string& label)`-definition isn't a member-function of `Deque`.

Comment: Strongly recommend against including Node.cpp in Deque.h. Instead include Node.h and compile and link Node.cpp. Ditto Deque.cpp in main.cpp.

Comment: So #include "Deque.cpp" in main.cpp?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> #include "Node.cpp"
> ```

Don't ever include source files. If you do this in `Deque.h`, at most one source file can include `Deque.h`. This greatly diminishes its reusability.

> 'head' was not declared in this scope

`head` isn't indeed declared in the free function `void print_queue(std::string& label)`. Perhaps you instead intended to define the member function `void Deque::print_queue(std::string& label)`, where the member variable `head` is declared.

Comment: So I should just include both .h files in my main function? How will Deque.cpp be used if I don't include it somewhere?

Comment: You should include a header in any source files that use function declarations or class definitions from the header. You'll need to compile `Deque.cpp` and link it with the other translation units.